# Use Variable in drawRect

Tags: objective-c, drawrect

Have a segue FirstView (which works) where an NSInteger value is set; this value gets passed (also successfully) to ViewController. All ViewController does is use `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {` in CustomDraw to create graphics (this works when it's a single view app and the integer value is hardcoded). Set the property in the .h, synthesized in the .m - but the value which passes from FirstView to ViewController does not pass to CustomDraw and is 0 so the graphics are not drawn.

In FirstView.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger _value;
```

In FirstView.m

```
if (row == 1) {
    __value=50;
    NSLog(@"Set pid to:%ld", (long)__value); //It's 50
```

In ViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger _value;
```

In ViewController.m

```
@synthesize _value;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Received value:%ld", (long)_value); // Still 50
```

CustomDraw.h

```
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) NSInteger _value;
```

CustomDraw.m

```
@synthesize _value;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        // Receive value and draw graphics

        NSLog(@"Custom:%ld", (long)_value); // It's 0
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you pass the value *from FirstView to ViewController*? Declaring and synthesizing a property – by the way since Xcode 6 you don't need to synthesize properties manually – is not sufficient.

Comment: @synthesize - works.

Comment: Didn't know that. Learning from the tutorials on the internet - and yes, many (especially for obj-c) are not up to date. Please provide a suggestion.

Comment: You need to share the value in code between the classes. Properties with the same name in different classes are not synchronized.

Comment: Do not prefix property names with an underscore. Do not bother using `@synthesize`. That hasn't been needed in years.

Comment: How is ViewController.m's `_value` set to 50? There is no way that the `__value=50;` line in FirstView.m has any effect on the _value in ViewController. Also, you do not need to specify `readwrite` or `assign` those property declarations.

Comment: All, thanks for the suggestions. I kept researching - decided to use the very popular option of NSUserDefaults (which I already use in other apps). Seems like overkill - especially since I don't need the value for the next app session. But it works. Thanks.